# javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Cannot instantiate class: org.apache.naming.java.javaURLContextFactory

Tags: jira, hsqldb, jira-plugin, atlassian-plugin-sdk

I'm trying to get a connection to jira's default database (HSQL) using the following java code:

```
InitialContext initalContext = new InitialContext();            
Context context = (Context) initalContext.lookup("java:comp/env");          
dataSource = (DataSource) context.lookup("jdbc/JiraDS");
```

I have added `catalina.jar`, `naming-factory.jar`, `naming-java.jar` and `tomcat-juli.jar` as per the answer given in stack overflow.

However, I'm still getting an error:

```
javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Cannot instantiate class: org.apache.naming.java.javaURLContextFactory [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.naming.java.javaURLContextFactory]
  at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(Unknown Source)
  at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(Unknown Source)
  at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(Unknown Source)
  at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(Unknown Source)
  at in.componence.jira.plugin.util.JiraDataSourceUtil.getConnectionToJiraDB(JiraDataSourceUtil.java:40)
```

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

The Classloader does not see org.apache.naming.java.javaURLContextFactory. Which jar-file contains the binary of the class? It has to be on the classpath. May be there are multiple classloaders present abd the moaning one is not the one in your focus?

Comment: thanks for your reply but i am not getting... Which jar-file contains the binary of the class?. can you ask me in detail...

Comment: %CATALINA_HOME%\target\container\tomcat7x\apache-tomcat-7.0.52\lib